# Creating an efficient way of sending integers over a network. TCP

Tags: java, performance, networking, byte, data-stream

How can I convert integer values to byte arrays and then send them over a byte stream to the client program which converts the byte array back to an integer?

My program is a pingpong game. Once run it creates a server which a client connects to over the internet using an object stream *right now*. All is working well, but it doesn't seem very efficient. By that I mean the ball is stuttering back and forth while it is trying to keep in sync via the *update loop*. I may have programmed it loosely, but it was the best I could come up with. I hope someone who knows a lot more about how this kind of thing works can help me clear some things up.

My question put straight. I need to know a better way to send the ball positions and player position over the internet more efficiently. Currently the time it takes is too long. Although, I could be updating it the wrong way.

The way the streams are constructed:

```
    oostream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
    oostream.flush();
    oistream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

This is player 2's update loop:

```
            IntData id = new IntData();

            while (running) {

                id.ballx = ballx;
                id.bally = bally;
                id.player2Y = player2Y;
                oostream.writeObject(id);
                oostream.flush();

                Thread.sleep(updaterate);

                id = (IntData) oistream.readObject();
                player1Y = id.player1Y;
                    ballx = id.ballx;
                bally = id.bally;

            }
```

Player 1 is the server host.
This is player 1's update loop:

```
            IntData id = new IntData();

            while (running) {

                id = (IntData) oistream.readObject();
                player2Y = id.player2Y;
                ballx = id.ballx;
                bally = id.bally;

                Thread.sleep(updaterate);

                id.ballx = ballx;
                id.bally = bally;
                id.player1Y = player1Y;
                oostream.writeObject(id);
                oostream.flush();

            }
```

Comment: Try removing the sleeps. `oostream` will still await a full object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest not using full serialization for simply primitives. use `DataInputStream` and the like instead:

```
dostream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
distream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Then read with:

```
 ballx=distream.readInt();
 bally=distream.readInt();
```

and write as:

```
 dostream.writeInt(ballx);
 dostream.writeInt(bally);
```

Also I suggest you not sleep awaiting data on both sides. Sleep on one and let the second simply await for a full set of data before transmitting by cutting out the `Thread.sleep()` there.

Comment: Oh yeah thats right about the wait. The one will wait on read, thanks.

Comment: +1 You don't need the flush() after construction. There is nothing to flush yet. You don't need a sleep at either end either: read() will block at the receiver, and flush() will send at the sender.

Comment: Thanks. The sleep is only for testing it on my own computer, for simulation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

this is the function im using everytime for it
its pretty simple and works perfectly but the function is not rly needed (just very easy to use)

```
public static final byte[] parseIntToByteArray(int i){
    byte[] b = {(byte)(i >> 24),
                (byte)(i >> 16),
                (byte)(i >> 8),
                (byte)i};
    return b;
}
```

to get it back:

```
int xy = (bytearray[0] << 24 | bytearray[1] << 16 | bytearray[2] << 8 | bytearray[3]);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It sign-extends negative bytes. More is required. But it is already provided by DataInput and DataOutput.

Comment: One can use >>> instead of >> to prevent the sign-extension. Or a ByteBuffer.

Comment: No. The sign extension happens during reconstruction. `>>>` doesn't help. Try it on `-65408.`